# Are there any good work-queue-based frameworks?

Tags: frameworks, queue

I've been thinking about writing a web framework (think Struts, Ruby on Rails, Seaside) that is based on the idea of a work queue.  I'm looking to see if anyone has done such a framework before.

I'm happy to check out frameworks that are for processing requests and spitting back results, but *aren't* web (HTTP).  I'm *not* looking for a work queue system (think Starling, Workling, Amazon's Queue Service, JMS) itself, but rather a processing system that runs atop one.

I'm not so particular about language; what I'm most interested in is commentary and/or lessons learned.  (Thus queue-based systems still in their infancy are probably of less interest.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but it sounds a lot like [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). It doesn't expose the actual work queue, but it is centered around asynchronous work items. See the description of Deferreds [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/core/documentation/howto/async.html)

Answer (score 1):

What about the Windows Workflow Foundation for ASP.Net?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out [beanstalkd](http://xph.us/software/beanstalkd/) , or more heavy weight message queue systems such as [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)